# How to pass a class instance as parameter

Tags: c#

I have created a class and I am adding to this class values (when I debug they are there) however once the method below is called the client is empty. Can you please advise what am I doing wrong? I understand that the class is a reference type, however how can I make use of this? I am just a bit confused.

According to this I don't see where I am going wrong https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264525/best-oop-practice-in-c-passing-the-object-as-parameter-vs-creating-a-new-insta

Please explain

```
public class SesEmailSender : IEmailSender
{
        ClientAmazon clientAmazon;

        public SesEmailSender()
        {
            var clientAmazon = new ClientAmazon();
        }

        public async Task<SendResponse> SendAsync(EmailMessage email)
        {
            var response = new SendResponse();
            var mailMessage = CreateEmailMessage(email);

            using (var client = SesSenderExtension.GetClient(clientAmazon))
            {
                await client.SendEmailAsync(mailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return response;
        }
}  

public static class SesSenderExtension
{
    public static ClientAmazon JsonParse()
    {
        var myJsonString = File.ReadAllText("msgSettings.json");
        var myJObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);

        var client = new ClientAmazon()
                {
                    AccessKeyID = myJObject.SelectToken("AccessKeyId").Value<string>(),
                    SecretAccessKey = myJObject.SelectToken("SecretAccessKey").Value<string>()
                };
        return client;
    }
    
    public static AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient GetClient(ClientAmazon client)
    {
        return new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(client.AccessKeyID, client.SecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
    }
}
callin in the console 
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetAuthentificationDetails();
            SesSenderExtension.JsonParse();
            var sesEmailSender = new SesEmailSender();
            var email = new EmailMessage()
            {
                Sender = "ccc@gmail.com",
                Reciever = "xxx@gmail.com",
                Subject = "test",
                Body = "test",
            };

            var response = sesEmailSender.Send(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your constructor to this. Right now you are assigning to a local variable instead of your class property.

So change the constructor from

```
public SesEmailSender()
{
    var clientAmazon = new ClientAmazon();
}
```

To this:

```
public class SesEmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    ClientAmazon clientAmazon;

    public SesEmailSender()
    { 
        // remove var here
        clientAmazon = new ClientAmazon();
    }

    public async Task<SendResponse> SendAsync(EmailMessage email)
    {
        var response = new SendResponse();
        var mailMessage = CreateEmailMessage(email);

        using (var client = SesSenderExtension.GetClient(clientAmazon))
        {
            await client.SendEmailAsync(mailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Update based on your comments:**

In your Program.cs you are doing this:

```
SesSenderExtension.JsonParse();
```

This will set the credentials on a *different* `ClientAmazon`.
Then later you create a NEW `ClientAmazon` in your constructor. That instance **will not** have any credentials set on it.

To get around this you could do something like this:

1. Get the configured client from `SesSenderExtension.JsonParse()`
2. Refactor `SesEmailSender` to take a `ClientAmazon` in it's constructor
3. Pass the `ClientAmazon` to the `SesEmailSender` constructor.
4. Use the `ClientAmazon` that you passed into the constructor.
5. Profit

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetAuthentificationDetails();
    var client = SesSenderExtension.JsonParse();
    var sesEmailSender = new SesEmailSender(client);
    var email = new EmailMessage()
    {
        Sender = "ccc@gmail.com",
        Reciever = "xxx@gmail.com",
        Subject = "test",
        Body = "test",
    };

    var response = sesEmailSender.Send(email);
}
```

```
public class SesEmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    ClientAmazon _clientAmazon;

    public SesEmailSender(ClientAmazon clientAmazon)
    { 

        _clientAmazon = clientAmazon;
    }

    public async Task<SendResponse> SendAsync(EmailMessage email)
    {
        var response = new SendResponse();
        var mailMessage = CreateEmailMessage(email);

        using (var client = SesSenderExtension.GetClient(_clientAmazon))
        {
            await client.SendEmailAsync(mailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, thats not it. I have done that but its still null

Comment: its there   public static AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient GetClient(ClientAmazon client)
    {
        return new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(client.AccessKeyID, client.SecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
    }

Comment: @orbitobalgin: This answer *is* the reason that `clientAmazon` is null in `SesEmailSender`. Unfortunately your question contains quite a lot of code, and the description is not clear in terms of which method is called and what is null. If this answer doesn't solve the problem for you, please edit a [mcve] into the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet i am sorry, what answer? I will have a look

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your problem is the initialization of ```ClientAmazon```. In Program.cs you are calling ```SesSenderExtension.JsonParse();```. That call configures a ```ClientAmazon``` that you are NOT using anywhere.

Comment: @JOSEFtw i see, so what should i do differntly?

Comment: Thank you so much. SO my passing was ok, but i was creating extra reference and completely different variable. Thank you so much

Comment: No worries! Please note that in your ```SendAsync``` method you are creating a new ```SendResponse``` at the top and then you are not doing anything with it, just returning...